# Ubuntu (Wubi) won't boot; stuck at grub command line

Tags: boot, grub2, wubi

Ubuntu installed by Wubi works fine on first boot. However, on later boots, it gets stuck at grub command line. I can input. I can choose to exit and boot windows 7.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean when you cold boot everything is fine
but when you warm boot (e.g. reboot) there is an error ?

Comment: Probably the root.disk is being corrupted. Hard shutdowns likely the cause. Add more info about what is happening between 'first boot' and 'later'

Answer (score 0):

It should be a bug in thw Wubi installer.
try to defrag. your hdd and see what happends after that.
it should proberly help :)

Comment: This is on a higher level, and a defrag may not help... But thanks for giving an answer!